# Unable to send JSON string through java Runtime.getRuntime.exec();

Tags: java, json, curl

I'm trying to send a JSON string using CURL command and Runtime.getRuntime.exec() function.

My JSON string is something like:

```
String jsonString = "{\"object\":[\"something\",\"another something\"]}"
```

I'm trying to send this string using the following function:

```
Process p;
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"curl","someURL","-H","Content-Type:application/json","-d",jsonString,"-u","something:something"}
```

Once I execute the following lines and parse the output, I get an error saying that the JSON document is not valid. When I try the same command using command line, it works just fine. I think the problem is with the JSON string as the escape characters are also being send as a part of the JOSN data and hence the invalid JSON data output.

Is there anything that I have done wrong or is there any other way that I have to execute the command.

Comment: I faced the problem.
i made a string and passed the string in Runtime.getRuntime().exec("command_string")
But this didnt work.
my string command was - "curl --header \"Content-Type: application/json\"  --data  '{\"username\":\"xyz\",\"password\":\"xyz\"}' --request POST http://localhost:8080/mm/connectiondebugger/jerseydebuggerapi"

when i tried the code in your question - it worked for me :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just tried like with a modification and worked

```
    String jsonString = "{\"object\":[\"something\",\"another something\"]}";

    ProcessBuilder ps = new ProcessBuilder(new String[] { "curl", "http://localhost:8338", "-H",
            "Content-Type:application/json", "-d", jsonString, "-u", "something:something" });
    ps.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process pr = ps.start();  

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new 

    InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    pr.waitFor();

    in.close();
    System.exit(0);
```

For server side  I used Pippo webframework and it returned me an OK string

```
     % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

    0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:-     -:--     0
    100    46    0     2  100    44    329   7247 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  7333
    OK
```

Server side code:

```
public class PippoApplication extends Application {

private final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PippoApplication.class);

@Override
protected void onInit() {


    POST("/", new RouteHandler() {

        @Override
        public void handle(RouteContext routeContext) {
            System.out.println(routeContext.getRequest().getBody());
            routeContext.send("OK");
        }
    });


}
```

}